# PCL execution error

Tags: point-cloud-library

I'm fairly new to the PCL and linux in general. I'm having trouble following the examples in documentation. None of the examples execute.The code compiles fine and a executable is generated. But I keep getting a permission denied error. The usual chmod and chown dont work. I've tried reinstalling PCL. What am I missing here ?

Here is the output from terminal https://www.dropbox.com/s/pjv8utctnokpihd/error.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dump you provide it looks like you are working in a mounted disk (/media/chaitanya/); possibly it was mounted with `noexec` or something. Try running `mount` to see.

Alternatively try working in your home directory:

```
cd ~
cp -r /media/chaitanya/work/learn-pcl/ ./
```

etc.